# Making div appear and disappear when scrolling

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a div appear and disappear at the top of the window. This is what I've got so far: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdf1xt2t/4/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#div_to_show").hide(); //hide your div initially
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // once top of div is scrolled past
        if($('body').scrollTop() >= $("#div_to_scroll_past").offset().top) {
            console.log('past top');
            $("#div_to_show").hide(); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#div_to_show").hide(); //hide your div initially
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // once bottom of div is scrolled past
        if($('body').scrollTop() >= ( $("#div_to_scroll_past").offset().top + $("#div_to_scroll_past").outerHeight() )) {
            console.log('past bottom');
            $("#div_to_show").show(); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
    });
});    
</script>
```

It works here if you don't scroll to fast. Scroll up too fast and the div that first appeared doesn't disappear again. How can this be solved?

Another (big) problem is:
it's working in JSFiddle but not in my webpage. (?????) The div to be shown is correctly initially being hidden but does not appear when scrolling down.

Eddy

Comment: Apart from it not working on Firefox or IE at all because of only using `body` as the scroll reference, it looks fine to me. Writing the code twice isn't very efficient though. http://jsfiddle.net/1d6ng3cw/

Comment: Please check this if it does -http://jsfiddle.net/mtdooaqh/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Made a combination of your two codes provided to A. solve the Firefox and IE compatibility Issue and fix B. that when scrolling up fast the div still disappears.  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oanxf36t/)  Big problem still exists though, in my webpage the div to show still does not appear.

Comment: On a Mac I'm using Safari (8.0.7) and Firefox (41.0.2) to check.

Comment: Do you have a link to that page?

Comment: Looks like there's another bug there - `var d = $('gototopbutton');` is an undefined object. It's a small script at the bottom of the page, not sure if it's completely related but I suspect it's interfering.